# how to refer to a cell in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have run the following code

```
from pandas_datareader.data import Options
aapl = Options('aapl', 'yahoo')
data = aapl.get_all_data()
data.head()
```

and I got following out put
[image]

let's say under 'Vol' there is one cell with value '13', how do i access that value in this dataframe? 
at first, i have tried data['Vol'] to get 'Vol' column but it failed

```
df=data.loc[(slice(None), slice(None), 'put'),'Vol':'Vol'] 
df
```

[image]

it seems i cannot get only 'Vol' column for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `loc` - it return all values with `13` in column `Vol`:

```
mask = data['Vol'] == 13
vals = data.loc[mask, 'Vol']
```

For first `13` select by position by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) or [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
first = vals.iloc[0]
first = vals.iat[0]
```

Comment: what if i dont know it's first or nth item?

Comment: Hmmm, it depends what need. but obviously is necesary get all values, first or last (`vals.iloc[-1]`).